# Add Change access option to the Custom Widget of Azure API Management Developer portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am creating a Custom widget for Azure API Management developer portal. We are following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-extend-custom-functionality) to create the widget. I want to hide this widget after user sign in. For this I need an option for change access so that widget is not visible to the authenticated users. I dont see an option for changing the access for the custom widget but same option is available for the in-bult widgets. Screen shot added here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure APIM developer portal team confirmed this feature is not available as of now and the work around is provided here : https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/2399

Answer (score 0):

In administrative mode, on the bottom left of the Developer Portal you should have a small menu.

[image]

Click on the "Roles" button and select "Authenticated" or "Anonymous".

The Sign In/Sign Out menu works in the same way.

You may need to add a new boolean value to your widget, do check if the user is authenticated or not, and set the visibility of the widget there. And then, when you are in the "Edit widget" menu, you should see this new option and select if visible or not based on that logic.

Comment: Here  I am talking about the widgets in the Managed portal. What you are suggesting is for the widgets in the self hosted developer portal and we are aware of that. For the managed portal,  Azure Developer portal developer mentioned that this feature is not available yet. Here is the comment : https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/2399